# How do I keep a button depressed in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, button, components

I want to create a navigation panel in my C++.net application, and I want to keep a button (or similar component) depressed to show that is the page the user is currently on.

**Here is a image of what I mean:**

[image: Add/remove programs]

**How do I create a button that looks like that. (After further inspection, I think it's not a button, however, I cannot figure out the exact control unless it is a image drawn on the screen.)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is commonly called an "Outlook Bar". There are several examples at codeproject.com